Why does feather read fail after creating a column with qcut?
I'm trying to create a new column in a dataframe using qcut and save the resulting dataframe using feather. When I try to read the dataframe is give error 'ArrowInvalid: Ran out of field metadata, likely malformed'.
qcut should return a category column.
I have many category columns on my data - only this one causes an issue.
import pyarrow.feather as feather
import pandas as pd
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'],
        'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# write and read with feather
feather.write_feather(df, 'C:\Projects\data')
df2 = feather.read_feather('C:\Projects\data')

# create a new column with qcut
df['test'] = pd.qcut(df['Age'], 2, duplicates='drop')
print(df)

# repeat write and read with feather
feather.write_feather(df, 'C:\Projects\data')
df2 = feather.read_feather('C:\Projects\data')

Thanks

This works df['test'] = pd.qcut(df['Age'], 2, duplicates='drop').astype('str').astype('category') - though not sure why
